# BackgroundWorker ShowDialog causes app to stop

Tags: c#, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have been trying to implement a BackgroundWorker into my application, and so far, it has not gone well. On a new thread, I want to open up a new Form that will have a progressbar and a label to report progress, however, this is not working well. When I call ShowDialog, the application does not respond any more. Is this because my code is running from my Form1, and I am showing WorkingForm? Also, can this be implemented cleaner?

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<object> param = new List<object>();
    object[] objectparams = new object[1];
    objectparams[0] = null;
    Opera opera = new Opera();
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo clearOpera = opera.GetType().GetMethod("ClearOpera");
    param.Add(clearOpera);
    param.Add(opera);
    param.Add(objectparams);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(param);
}

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Browser.cancelPending = true;
}
private delegate void getnewform();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    mainForm main = new mainForm();
    TestURLGUI4.Form1 form = (TestURLGUI4.Form1)Application.OpenForms[0];
    var variab = (bool)form.Invoke(new getnewform(main.AskForConfirmation));
        List<object> param = e.Argument as List<object>;

        List<object> result = new List<object>();
        var method = param[0] as MethodInfo;
        object[] parameters = param[2] as object[];
        if (parameters[0] == null)
        {
            result.Add(method.Invoke(param[1], null));
            result.Add(false);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(method.Invoke(param[1], parameters));
            if (parameters.Contains(true))
                result.Add(true);
        }
        int progress = (100 * Browser.progressValue) / Browser.progressMax;

        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress);

        // If the BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending property is true, cancel
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
            Browser.cancelPending = true;
        }
        e.Result = result;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm form = (TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm)Application.OpenForms[1];
        form.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        form.label1.Text = Browser.progressValue + "/" + Browser.progressMax;
        Application.DoEvents();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    List<object> param = e.Result as List<object>;
    if (e.Cancelled == false && param.Contains(true))
    {
        Display.DisplayURLs(param[0] as SortableBindingList<URL>);
        TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm form = (TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm)Application.OpenForms[1];
        MessageBox.Show("Done");

    }
    else if (e.Cancelled == false && param.Contains(false))
    {
        TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm form = (TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm)Application.OpenForms[1];
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }


}

    public class mainForm
{
public void AskForConfirmation()
{
    TestURLGUI4.Form1 form = (TestURLGUI4.Form1)Application.OpenForms[0];
    var workingForm = new TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm();
    workingForm.ShowDialog(form);
    workingForm.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;

}
}
```

Edit:
Ok, I have updated my code according to the suggestions, and now, this produces a stackoverflowexception in System.Windows.Forms.dll:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    mainForm main = new mainForm();
    TestURLGUI4.Form1 form = (TestURLGUI4.Form1)Application.OpenForms[0];
        List<object> param = e.Argument as List<object>;
        List<object> result = new List<object>();
        var method = param[0] as MethodInfo;
        object[] parameters = param[2] as object[];
        if (parameters[0] == null)
        {
            result.Add(method.Invoke(param[1], null));
            result.Add(false);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(method.Invoke(param[1], parameters));
            if (parameters.Contains(true))
                result.Add(true);
        }
        int progress = (100 * Browser.progressValue) / Browser.progressMax;

        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress);

        // If the BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending property is true, cancel
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
            Browser.cancelPending = true;
        }
        e.Result = result;


}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TestURLGUI4.Form1 form1 = (TestURLGUI4.Form1)Application.OpenForms[0];
    if (Application.OpenForms.Count >= 2)
    {
        TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm form2 = (TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm)Application.OpenForms[1];
        form2.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        form2.label1.Text = Browser.progressValue + "/" + Browser.progressMax;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    else if(Application.OpenForms.Count == 1)
    {
        var workingForm = new TestURLGUI4.WorkingForm();
        workingForm.ShowDialog(form1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make youyr life a lot easier. Do the confirm before you kick the thread off, and competely and totally remove the need for Application.OpenForms. It's an almost guaranteed race, the form might be closed after you get a reference. Don't even want to think about what your explicit cast of an index on it might leave you with after a few changes to the app.

Comment: Can someone take a look at my updated code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a `BackgroundWorker` is to invoke code on another thread (not the UI thread).  By calling `Invoke` in the `DoWork` method, you're completely circumventing the purpose of `BackgroundWorker`.  Do all your UI work before you start the worker.  If you need to interact with the user *while* the worker is working, do it in the `ProgressChanged` handler--it runs on the UI thread and you don't need to use `Invoke` in `ProgressChanged`.

By invoking UI work in `DoWork`, you run the risk of a deadlock, which will hang your program

Answer (score 0):

you cant run UI on other threads. Has to be on the main thread.

Instantiate the UI before you start the new thread. In the new thread use cross thread invoke methods on the controls you want to work with. Look here for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Comment: Unless you are going to suggest an actual solution, this would be better posted as a comment.